What to do now that Gnome 44 runtime is no longer supported?
Info: org.gnome.Platform//44 is end-of-life, with reason:
The GNOME 44 runtime is no longer supported as of March 20, 2024. 
Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.

This was the message from my flatpak updating process today.
I have had flatpak installed for ~ 2 years as it has proven to be faster on graphics intense applications. It's current version is Flatpak 1.12.7. Below is a list of current flatpak apps:
$ flatpak list
Name                Application ID           Version  Branch      Installation
Martin Abente Laha… ….github.tchx84.Flatseal 2.2.0    stable      system
Matthew Jakeman     …akeman.ExtensionManager 0.5.0    stable      system
Freedesktop Platfo… org.freedesktop.Platform 22.08.24 22.08       system
Freedesktop Platfo… org.freedesktop.Platform 23.08.16 23.08       system
Mesa                …top.Platform.GL.default 24.0.4   22.08       system
Mesa (Extra)        …top.Platform.GL.default 24.0.4   22.08-extra system
Mesa                …top.Platform.GL.default 24.0.5   23.08       system
Mesa (Extra)        …top.Platform.GL.default 24.0.5   23.08-extra system
Intel               …op.Platform.VAAPI.Intel          22.08       system
Intel               …op.Platform.VAAPI.Intel          23.08       system
openh264            …sktop.Platform.openh264 2.1.0    2.0         system
openh264            …sktop.Platform.openh264 2.1.0    2.2.0       system
openh264            …sktop.Platform.openh264 2.4.1    2.4.1       system
GNOME Application … org.gnome.Platform                45          system
GNOME Application … org.gnome.Platform                46          system
Yaru Gtk Theme      org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Yaru            3.22        system
Yaru-magenta Gtk T… ….Gtk3theme.Yaru-magenta          3.22        system
Firefox             org.mozilla.firefox      125.0.1  stable      system

All the same, it seems my system was still provided with a (partial?) update:
        ID                          Branch   Op  Remote   Download
 1. [✓] org.gnome.Platform.Locale   44       u   flathub   1.7 kB / 340.9 MB
 2. [✓] org.gnome.Platform.Locale   46       u   flathub  17.9 kB / 367.5 MB
 3. [✓] org.gnome.Platform          46       u   flathub   2.1 MB / 346.4 MB
 4. [✓] org.gnome.Platform          44       u   flathub   1.0 kB / 321.4 MB

But in my case I have Ubunto 22.04 and Gnome 42.5 . . . I was a bit fearful of installing the first iteration of the later 24.04 LTS version.
So can I presume that I need to migrate to Ubuntu 24.04 to enjoy this doubtless wonderous benefit of Gnome 46 ?

As you might know, Ubuntu does not use flatpack, and I am not sure who support those flathub packages. The native Ubuntu packages are supported by Canonical employees throughout the support cycle of the release.

Ask whoever maintains whichever antique flatpak you're using? You haven't even said which ones, so how can anyone here help you?

@muru  I am using flatpak version 1.12.7 and it is provided/maintained by flathub (who else ?). I installed it myself and updates are automatic. To: mikewhatever - I expect that the maintainers of those flathub applications are the app builders themselves, by and large. I prefer the flatpak system rather than snap or apt for certain graphical apps like Firefox, Inkscape, etc.

There isn't any PPA that has GNOME 46. You need to install Ubuntu 24.04 in order to upgrade the GNOME desktop environment to version 46.
In Ubuntu 24.04 the flatpak application deployment framework for desktop apps is provided by the flatpak package. You can find many applications that are compatible with the GNOME 46 desktop environment at Flathub.
